# NodeJs & Mongodb:Cannot Update (Patch). Returns Success but doesn't change anything

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

*I have been trying to update my "Orders" in which product, quantity, and _id are contents. After i run patch it return success but doesn't actually change anything.*
My API Update code screen shot

[**Patch/Update code here**. I am new so i cannot have image directly embedded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KqcV.jpg)

Postman Screen shot: In this, i use body in postman to store in an object and patch it 
[This is my POSTMAN api test screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBoID.jpg)

My model of Orders

[Model of Orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYwiB.jpg)

> Patch code:

```
router.patch('/:id',(req,res)=>{
  var update = {};
  for(var up of req.body)
  {
    update[up.new]=up.value
  }
  console.log(update )
  Product.update({_id:req.params.id},{$set:update})
    .exec()
    .then(result=>{
    res.status(200).json(
      {
        Message:'Product Updated',
        Request:{
          type:'GET',
          url:'http://localhost:5000/orders/'+req.params.id
        }
      }
    )
  })
    .catch(err=>{
    res.status(500).json(err)
    console.log(err)
  })
})
```

> Model Code

```
var express = require('express') var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
var orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  product:{type:String, required:'true'},
  quantity:{type:Number,default:1}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order',orderSchema,'Order');
```

Comment: Please `console.log(result)`

Comment: @KingStone it gives { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }

Comment: `ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0` means, updated nothing

Comment: for debug, please `find` with `req.params.id` before `update`

Comment: Or, Please use `findByIdAndUpdate` instead `update`

Comment: @KingStone i have used req.params.id before update

Comment: Please `find()`, or let's disscuss in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192736/test-mmm

Comment: @KingStone , I was updating Product when i had "Orders" to update. Thank You, for corresponding

Answer (score 1):

First you don't have to specify _id in your mongoose schema, MongoDB create it automatically for you with a version index also. The problem might only comes from that.

If it returns success but doesn't affect any entry it means that no entry was found in the first place. When doing `Product.update({_id:req.params.id},{$set:update})` no model is found. Maybe try : `{_id: req.params.id.toString()}`.